# Standard evaluation script for conll POS tagging

Tags: nlp

There is a standard perl script for chunking task for conll 2000. Is there any standard evalution script for POS tagging evaluation as well?
   Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to use just Perl or are you ok with another language ?

Comment: If there is a python one, that will be great. I am just wondering whether there is an officially published standard evaluation script. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to evaluate a POS tagger is the token and sentence accuracy.

There is many tools to perform this task:

1. You can try to use OpenNLP toolkit to evaluate your POS tagger http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger.eval.tool
2. You can also use NLTK toolkit to evaluate your system http://streamhacker.com/2011/03/23/analyzing-tagged-corpora-nltk-part-speech-taggers/
3. Finally, this will be also interesting for you http://people.sutd.edu.sg/~yue_zhang/doc/doc/eng_pos_files/evaluate.py